# GKE Workload Identity binding to IAM very slow (~1 min)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I'm using [Workload Identity with GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity) so that a namespaced pod can get access to a GCP resource. I noticed that it takes ~1 min for the binding between IAM and GKE accounts to take place which is way too slow for my application.

```
curl -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google" http://169.254.169.254/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email
# => myapp@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com


# Bind GKE service account to IAM service account
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
      myapp@myproject.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
      --member "myproject.svc.id.goog[user-1/myapp]" \
      --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser


# ... Takes 1min of 403 until I can actually access the GCP resource
```

Is this normal behaviour? What's an alternative for instantly giving access to a pod?

Comment: This delay is due to Kubernetes API server needs to update its cache to reflect the changes made in IAM and its normal behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is normal.

Google Cloud IAM has various caching layers which means it takes time for [access change propagation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/access-change-propagation) to complete. This makes applying IAM changes "eventually consistent".

Additionally, there is a [known limitation](https://%3E%20https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity#restrictions) of several seconds for a metadata server using Workload Identity to become available to a pod:

> The GKE metadata server **takes a few seconds** to start accepting requests on a newly created Pod. Therefore, attempts to authenticate using Workload Identity within the first few seconds of a Pod's life might fail. Retrying the call will resolve the problem. See Troubleshooting for more details.

You can use an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) in your pod to confirm the [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/workload-identity#instance_metadata) is behaving properly (e.g. `curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor:google' http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1`...) before your main application container starts. That way everything is ready when your app code starts running.

> What's an alternative for instantly giving access to a pod?

This depends on your application needs. Why does each pod need a new service account? Some alternatives include:

- Using a pool of preexisting service accounts and cycling their permissions and pod usage (e.g. remove from pod, apply any changes, use on the next pod)
- Pass in API keys or other needed values via [Kubernetes Secrets mounts](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets-as-files-from-a-pod)
- Mint and use [short lived access IAM tokens](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/create-short-lived-credentials-direct) for your Service Account

Comment: Thanks. I have several ephemeral pods spawned (in different namespaces) that might hold sensitive secrets. So I assumed using Workload Identity with KMS was the right solution. But looks like I might need to look elsewhere due to this limitation.

Cycling still won't work since it's the binding that is slow - even if I reuse the same single IAM account